# how to pass string to a url and get the image from the webserver to the java SE application

Tags: java

how to pass string to a url in java. i want to download an image from a web server. before downloading a image i want to pass some values to that image then after that i want to download the image. can someone help me. in Java SE application

Comment: What do you "pass string to a url"?  Is the String a cookie, a GET parameter, POST data, etc.  Use [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/), [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or a similar tool to figure this out.

Comment: basically that url contain a map. so im passing couple of locations. so i want to know how to do it. im confused with it. do u have any code samples for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [apache-commons-httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) for this. Works like a browser, you pass an URI and get an InputStream. Even has cookie and form emulation support.